# Possible to automatically set default web part properties?

Tags: 2013, web-part

We're currently developing an intranet solution for a client, and am wondering if we can deploy with various webpart properties configured in a default way.

For instance, I dont want the 'help text' populated whenever they add a new webpart, and would like the Chrome Type be 'Title' by default.

Is this possible, or something we just need to train the client on to do when adding new webparts? (and to make the styles consistent)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I say train them on how to use the web parts, they become more self sufficient and it can be confusing seeing duplicate web parts. You are talking about basic web part configuration of ootb web parts here. Now if you were building and deploying your own, then sure set the applicable default values so they are configured on use.

If users don't have the knowledge on how to be creating pages and adding web parts, they shouldn't really be creating content.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add a web part and then make the desired changes.

Now you can export this web part and upload it into Web Part Gallery. Advise users to use the new web part instead of default one.

Comment: I see. So it might then be wise to create 'custom' web parts for all popular web parts we would think they would be using?

Comment: Yes. That is the best approach.

Comment: You prefix your company name to the webpart name. This way user will know the correct web part and eliminate issues related to duplicate name.